# Magento 1.9.3.1 Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found

Tags: fatal-error, magento1.9.3.1, magento-core

I am getting error frontend and backend both side

Fatal error:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php:175 
Stack trace: 
#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Array) 
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write') 
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write') 
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter() 
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php on line 175
```

How can I fix the issue?